# What is the difference between a preprocessor macro with no arguments, and one with zero arguments

Tags: macros, c-preprocessor

Is there any reason to prefer

```
#define MY_MACRO() ..stuff..
```

to

```
#define MY_MACRO ..stuff..
```

Don't use macros is not a valid answer...

Comment: Since you added the C++ tag not using macros is a valid answer. If you just want to talk about the pre-processor just tag it as pre-processor and not C++

Comment: @Martin:  The preprocessor is as much a part of C++ as the STL is; should questions about the STL be tagged `[stl]` and not `[c++]` too?  It's true that macros should not be used most of the time in C++, but sometimes they can be extraordinarily helpful.

Comment: @James McNellis: In fact, it would be practically impossible to implement the Boost libraries without macros!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Replacement only occurrs for a function-like macro if the macro name is followed by a left parenthesis.  So, the following all invoke the function-like macro `MY_MACRO()`:

```
MY_MACRO()
MY_MACRO ( )
MY_MACRO
( )
```

But this would not:

```
MY_MACRO SomethingElse
```

It depends on how you are using the macro and what it is used for as to whether or not this is important.  Ideally, your macros will all have distinct names; if you reserve all-uppercase identifiers for macros, then it shouldn't matter whether you use an object-like or a function-like macro with zero parameters.

Aesthetically, it's usually (but not always) cleaner not to have function-like macros that take zero parameters.

Comment: As I noted below, if `MY_MACRO` is, say, filling in for a function that depends on environmental conditions (say, different functions for OS X and Windows), then using it without parenthesis allows you to pass that function via function pointers, which may be helpful.

Comment: So from this could I say that the below two macro definitions are functionally equivalent
   #define MIN0( )  X  < Y ?  X : Y                            
   #define MIN X  < Y ?  X : Y

Comment: One case where it would be nice to see a function-like macro would be where you execute statements that have no return value. Then it would just look strange to see `MY_MACRO;`, because it looks like a constant value is written as a statement. `MY_MACRO();` looks more clear in my opinion.

Answer (score 12):

I prefer to use `MY_MACRO()`, *with* parentheses, because it feels more like I'm calling a function. Otherwise it looks like I'm calling a constant:

```
MY_MACRO();
```

vs

```
MY_MACRO;
```

That is if the definition is used to call code, rather than just a simple constant value.

Comment: If `MY_MACRO` is just a wrapper for a function (one that is hidden somewhere presumably, or needs to change based on the environment, or something), then defining it without parenthesis would allow you to pass that function as a function pointer to other functions, which may or may not be useful.

Comment: @ChrisLutz From another perspective, it will also add another macro symbol to worry about. `struct state {int errno; /* ERROR!*/ };`

Answer (score 1):

Macro( x ) is preferrable when you have parameters to pass.  If you are doing a simple "replace" then, IMO, its preferrable to use #define BLAH ...